# solr query to search for blank fields

Tags: solr

I have apache solr search version 1.4

i want to search for all blank field but it's not working

query is :

```
select?q=-l_occupation_code%3A%5B%2A+TO+%2A%5D&fq=(member_id:332273%20OR%20member_id:7254)&fl=*&start=0&rows=50
```

using `-l_occupation_code:[* TO *]` to find all records for field l_occupation_code that contains the blank value.

please help

Answer (score 0):

I would try a slight variation of what you have here:

```
-l_occupation_code:["" TO *]
```

there can be some variation from the documentation currently online due to versions and field type.

Comment: this is working fine for me to search empty value. 

Now i want search for specific value along with empty value and that not working for me.

solr query:

(-l_occupation_code:["" TO *] OR l_occupation_code:100004)

select?q=(-l_occupation_code%3A%5B%22%22+TO+%2A%5D+OR+l_occupation_code%3A100004)&fq=(member_id:332273%20OR%20member_id:7254)&fl=*&start=0&rows=50&indent=on&sort=paid_status+desc,last_login_date+desc

It doesn't fetch any result.